# Pasar un string que contiene un array de 2 dimensiones a tipo array

Tags: javascript, array

he estado investigando sobre como pasar un array de 2 dimensiones que se encuentra en formato string a tipo array pero no he logrado como hacerlo.

Lo que quiero hacer es lo siguiente:

```
var arrayInString = "[[123, "abc], [456, "def"]]";
y convertir ese string a que me quede a 

var arr = [[123, "abc], [456, "def"]];
```

he tratado de hacerlo con el método split de la siguiente manera:

```
var car = '[["as", "aa"], [1, "aa"]]';

var ar = car.split(' ');

console.log(ar);
```

pero me arroja un solo array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías usar la función [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/eval):

```js
var arrayInString = "[[123, 'abc'], [456, 'def']]";
console.log(eval(arrayInString))

var car = '[["as", "aa"], [1, "aa"]]';
console.log(eval(car))
```

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
car = '[["as", "aa"], [1, "aa"]]';
resultado  = JSON.parse(car);
console.log(resultado)
```

como la misma documentancion explica [No_utilice_eval_innecesariamente](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/eval#No_utilice_eval_innecesariamente) porque alguien podria alterar tu codigo de manera maliciosa

**ejemplo:**

```js
car = '[["as", "aa"], [1, "aa"]];alert("esto es un injection de codigo")';
console.log(eval(car));
```